# External hard drive not detected after first boot : Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have the following problem and hope to find help by someone.
On the first boot of my Intel NUC after a longer period of time (for example,  over night) Xubuntu won't mount nor detect (`blkid`) my external USB 3.0 hard drive. Simply un- and replugging or switching it on and off won't help. I need to reboot my NUC in order to mount the hard drive.

Here's what `dmesg` says, when the hard drive is not detected:
https://paste.ubuntuusers.de/422738/

And here after the reboot, when it is detected:
https://paste.ubuntuusers.de/422743/

I should mention, that the problem persists, even after a complete clean reinstall of Ubuntu so I **shouldn't have "broken"** anything.
Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Comment: please show output of FSTAB